# LCM of 2 long long integers

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to calculate **lcm of 2 long long integers** as fast as possible .

For ex 
a=10^18
b=10^17

I was doing **lcm(a,b)=a*b/gcd(a,b)** for the integers
but for **long long there will be overflow**

What should be the **fastest way** to calculate it??

Comment: Are you effectively asking "when do I need to use a 'multiprecision' library, and how can I make best use of the `long long` to avoid that overhead"? Or are you okay with having some values overflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're always going to have overflow problems, especially whenever you have large coprime numbers. But to offset this a little, you can do as Michael suggest by writing `a * (b/gcd(a,b))`. Since `gcd(a,b)` is a divisor of both `a` and `b`, there's no worry about inaccurate results due to integer division.

Answer (score 0):

```
a*b <= c 
// When will a*b overflow c?
a > c/b
```

In your case `c` can be `LLONG_MAX`.